# Scraping websites in Java

Tags: java, screen-scraping, robots.txt

What I am trying to do is a take a list of URL's and download each URL's content (for indexing). The biggest problem is that if I encounter a link that is something like a facebook event that simply redirects to the login page I need to be able to detect and skip that URL. It seems as though the robots.txt file is there for this purpose. I looked into heritrix, but this seems like way more than I need. Is there a simpler tool that will provide information about robots.txt and scrape site accordingly?

(Also, I don't need to follow additional links and build up a deep index, I just need to index the individual pages in the list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just take the class you are interested in ie http://crawler.archive.org/xref/org/archive/crawler/datamodel/Robotstxt.html

Comment: I was kinda of hoping for something that did a bit more all in one package. It is possible that heritrix is the right thing for the job - maybe I just need a little more direction.

Comment: It's hard to answer what do you means exactly by index? If it's just download it. the class URL and the method openConnection is done for that. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29

Comment: I am looking to do a bit more than just download it. I would like to be able to check whether this is page that is "meaningful" (i.e. it is not behind a paywall or a login screen, etc), then download the html, and finally extract the plaintext for indexing. The biggest problem right now is figuring out if the page is meaningful.

Comment: This actually ended up working very well. Created a Robotstxt object and then called getDirectivesFor("<some-bot-type>").allows(url.getPath());